# React snake Game - Snake is not moving (setInterval problem)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

You can check the app from this;  [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-chaplygin-795mf?file=/src/App.tsx)

The logic of the snake movement is removing one square from its back and adding a new head basically. This creates an appearance like moving. But my interval doesn't seem to work correctly.

It works only for once then it's doing the same thing over and over again. Which means that state is not changing at all after one time.

I saw this in a video where someone was developing this game exactly this way but it was working. I can't see what's wrong with this code, thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven read your code but reading setinterval in the title makes me suggest you to use animation frames https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question. It was really interesting. The problem is this one.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(moveSnake, 1000);
  }, []);
```

`setInterval(moveSnake, 1000)`. This is using origin `moveSnake`. As functional components overwrite the whole state and functions, `moveSnake` changes. I think pointer to the array changes. And as it's using the origin pointer, `setInterval` can not change the state. I think you can update as follow.

```
useEffect(() => {
        setTimeOut(moveSnake, 1000);
      }, [snakeDots]);
```

Comment: actually setInterval keeps working but setting the state the same thing over and over again

Answer (score 0):

The "hidden" trick is that you are using `snakeDots` in your `moveSnake` method. Thus you will want to wait until it's done updating to trigger a new call.

You can make use of both `useEffect` and `setTimeout` to set a new timeout every time the snakeDots have been updated in the state. For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(moveSnake, 1000);
}, [snakeDots]);
```

Comment: The problem is this has done exactly this way in a class component and it was working. The setTimeout method will be a delay when direction of the snake changes. So It needs to be done with setInterval but you are correct that setInterval is not aware of new state. it does the same thing over and over again.